# Fetching objects using a variable from user input

Tags: javascript

I have been looking for the answer to this problem, but I haven't found exactly a similar issue.
I have created several objects (ob0, ob1, ob2) they all contain the same entries.. but on each object the value of the entries is different. i.e. ob0.brand has one value but oj1.brand has a different value.
I want to visualize the info of the objs on a website. there is a radio button that returns ob0, ob1, or ob2 accordingly to what is chosen.. and on one div class, the text content of the value of the entries is to be displayed.
the radio buttons value is named a var objSelc and try to use documentselctor to display ojbSelc.brand so that whatever the user selects would represent obj0.brand or obj1.brand etc. However, this returns an error.
Maybe it's not possible to use a var as the name of an object? or what workaround would there me??
btw I am a level 0.1 first month of learning, Any help will be appreciated.
here is the snippet of code in question:

so here is for example an inventory of a bike and the different components, brake pads, tires, chain etc. I have made different copies of these but replaced the content info.

```
 let UA = {
   brakes: "shimano b10s",
   backTire: " Bigben 26",
   frontTire: "bigben 20",
   bikeChain: " 1/32 single speed",
   motorBrand: " Bosch Intuvia, cargoline",
 };

let cargoCarla = {
   breaks: "shimano b10s",
   backTire: "big apple 24",
   frontTire: "big apple 20",
   bikeChain: "na",
   motorBrand: "na",
 };
```

Here comes some user input from the radio buttons from the HTML site

```
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var log = document.querySelector("#log");

 form.addEventListener(
  "submit",
  function (event) {
   var data = new FormData(form);
   var output = "";
   for (const entry of data) {
   output = output + entry[0] + "=" + entry[1] + "\r";
   }
   // log.innerText = output;
    event.preventDefault();
   var splitOut = output.split("=");
   var bikeSelc = splitOut[1].toString();
   showComponent.textContent = bikeSelc.brakes;
  },
  false
  );
```

In fact, bikeSelc does produce either UA or cargoCarla depending on which was selected.  but bikeSelc.brakes do not produce a result so JS is not reading the value of bikeSelc when added to.brakes. even though consel.log does give the proper variable.

```
 showComponent.textContent = UA.brakes;
```

This was just me hardcodingto see what it would look like on the DOM